# How to Put method using xUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net, moq, xunit

I try to test Update method using xUnit and I don't know how to do it, below is my code:

Put method in controller:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put([FromBody]BookDto book, [FromRoute]int id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    var isUpdated = _service.Update(book);
    if (!isUpdated)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

BookService update method:

```
public bool Update(BookDto book)
{
    var bookDb = _context.Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == book.Id);
    if(bookDb == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    bookDb.Title = book.Title;
    _context.SaveChanges();
    var existingAuthors = _context.Book_Authors.Where(x => x.BookId == book.Id).ToList();
    _context.Book_Authors.RemoveRange(existingAuthors);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var AuthorsId in book.AuthorsId)
    {
        var newBookAuthors = new Book_Author()
        {
            BookId = book.Id,
            AuthorId = AuthorsId
        };
        _context.Book_Authors.Add(newBookAuthors);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return true;
}
```

BookDto:

```
public class BookDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<int> AuthorsId { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions how to write PutMethod test using Moq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would suggest to collect the test cases:

   - **Given** an invalid book **When** I call put **Then** It returns bad request
   - **Given** a non-existing book **When** I call put **Then** It returns not Found
   - **Given** an existing book **When** I call put **Then** It returns ok
2. I would suggest to AAA pattern for each test case, for example:

   - **Arrange**: Setup a book service mock which returns false whenever someone calls the update
   - **Act**: Call your controller's put method
   - **Assert**: Verify that the returned result is not found as expected
3. Try to codify. For example

```
public void GivenANonExistingBook_WhenICallPut_ThenItReturnsNotFound()
{
    //Arrange
    var book = ...;
    var serviceMock = new Mock<IBookService>();
    serviceMock.Setup(svc => svc.Update(It.IsAny<BookDto>()))
               .Returns(false);

    var sut = new YourController(serviceMock.Object);

    //Act
    var result = sut.Put(book, 0);

    //Assert
    var actionResult = result as NotFoundResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
}
```

It is also a good practice to verify that the `Update` method of the service has been called only once with the `book` variable: `serviceMock.Verify(svc => svc.Update(book), Times.Once);`.

Comment: And how i can equal two fields for example if title was updated ?

Comment: @Ptrk12 That should be tested not on the controller level rather on the service level. Your unit tests should focus only the given method's functionality and not its dependencies' functionalities.